# jquery changing scrollleft position if statement(for image swap) depending on screen resolution

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

i have a horizontal sliding website.Depending on your scroll position I have image swaps to show where on the page you are. I want to be able depending on the screen resolution(browser resize) to change the scroll position if statement of image swaps. My code is:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
             if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 0)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 1040)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/naboutus.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 1041)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 2840)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nwhatwedo.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 2841)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 4640)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ntheory.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 4641)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 8424)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nportfolio.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 8424)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 11124)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nclients.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }else {
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ncontacts.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }


        });
```

This is for a screen resolution with width 1680px. So if the screen resolution width is say 1440px I would like the scroll position image swaps to change so effectively you would have say this code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
             if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 0)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 840)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/naboutus.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 841)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 1681)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nwhatwedo.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 1682)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 2522)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ntheory.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 2523)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 3363)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nportfolio.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 8224)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 10924)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nclients.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }else {
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ncontacts.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }


        });
```

The test site is on http://karpouzaki.com/fade/

I hope I explained it clearly enough what I m looking to do. If you need any more clarification please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered making the page into two sections? I.e. Sidebar, and Content. That way you can define a static width for "Content" as well, so that it fits the smallest resolution screen that you want and can dynamically adjust the space to the right of itself for bigger resolution screens. (i.e. `margin-right: auto; right: 0; padding-right: auto;`)

Comment: I have thought about it but I cant see it working. All my content sections are floated left all in the content area with a width of nearly 12000px. How would it dynamically adjust each section of content to adjust to the screen width with margin-right:auto?

Comment: Also this still wont solve my problem of adjusting the scroll position values depending on screen resolution. If I have a resolution of 1680px width my scroll positions work fine but if I say display it on an 1440px width screen my scroll positions are still changing depending on the 1680px width resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the **position** element of the "step" and "content" classes you created to **inherit**, you can detect whether or not a particular content section is in view of the client window.

### CSS

```
.step, .content
{
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

### jQuery sample 1

```
var diff = $('#content1').position().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

if ( diff <= 0 )
{
   $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/naboutus.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
}
```

When the "diff" value above reaches 0, that means that the left side of div#content1 is touching the left side of the client's browser.  When the value drops below zero, it means that the left side of the div is beginning to be hidden from the client's window.

You could then use the width of the client's browser to determine when to switch the wrapper's background image.

### jQuery Sample 2

```
var diff = $('#content2').position().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var content2Width = $('#content2').width();  

if ( ( diff - ( windowWidth - content2Width ) ) <= 0 )
{
   $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nwhatwedo.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
}
```

So, I'm thinking that if the width of the content div is greater than the client window, the above condition will essentially make sure that the user moves the scroll bar by that incremental amount, before the background image will change.  You could adjust the logic to change the image earlier in the scrolling process...

Comment: Interesting although how would you set the rest of the pages? I mean once it drops below 0 it changers the first image but once that content has gone by how would it tell to change it again since everything is below 0?

Comment: You would check each content div individually, because only one of them can have a `diff = 0` at a given time.  It will really depend on when you want to change the images.

Comment: Once content1 has been scrolled left and its content has left the screen I need the image swap to happen and the same would happen for content2 content3 content4 content5 etc. Once the first image swapp has happened then all the following scroll positions are below 0. So when the example content3 is visible I need it to display content3IMAGE once it has been scrolled out the screen I need the image to swap to the next contents image and so on

Comment: If you think of your content divs going left to right, they are in one long line.  If you check each div individually using `$(contentDivId).position().left - $(window).scrollLeft();` then at some point each div will have a left position of 0 (relative to the client window). Swap the image for each content div (separately) at the point that it crosses the 0 threshold. Content divs to the right of the one that you are checking will have a positive diff value until they are scrolled all the way into view and beyond.

Comment: So I ll need to create something similar to your jquery sample 2 answer for all my content sections. It will be a bit long from a programming point. Is the answer I posted which solved my problem(although I need to put it in a function to be called each time the window is resized) wrong or will it create problems at some point?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and seems to solve my problem:

```
            var wwidth = $(window).width();
    var spos1 = wwidth - 371;
    var spos2 = spos1+wwidth;
    var spos3 = spos2 + wwidth;
    var spos4 = spos3 + wwidth + $('.rightporto').width();
    var spos5 = spos4 + wwidth + $('.leftclients').width();

     if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 0)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= spos1)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/naboutus.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() > spos1)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= spos2)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nwhatwedo.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() > spos2 )&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= spos3)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ntheory.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() > spos3)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= spos4)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nportfolio.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() > spos4)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() <= spos5)){
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/nclients.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }else {
                  $(".wrapper").css('background','url(img/ncontacts.png) 95% top no-repeat fixed');
              }
```

is this an effective way of doing it? or is it incorrect from a programming point of view?